# How work PK in oracle

Tags: oracle, primary-key, toad

I got a task to review and change a PK field in a oracle table (I'm Postgresql and Sql Server guy) I check on TOAD constraints and found this:

```
PK_POI    Primary Key Disabled  Not Deferrable  Immediate  Not Validated  1    MI_PRINX
SYS_C0010910    Check Disabled  Not Deferrable  Immediate  Not Validated  1    "MI_PRINX" IS NOT NULL
```

For what I can see two constraint where created, but by my understanding a PK is already a `NOT NULL` field so why need two constraint?

Also I notice both constraint said are `Disable` but in my test I can insert null values but not the same id twice

So not sure if `Disable` constraint mean what I thought should mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable means what you think it means.

Regarding `NOT NULL` and `PRIMARY KEY`, they are two constraints. A primary key implies `NOT NULL`, but if you drop the primary key constraint, the check constraint is still there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665394/do-we-need-to-specify-not-null-for-primary-key-oracle-sql/13670533#13670533) for details.

Regarding "I can insert null values...": this is because both constraints are disabled.

Regarding "...but not the same id twice": a primary key constraint and the unique index that is used to enforce it are two different things. Can you check if there is an unique index on this column?

Comment: Yes, there is also an `PK_POI`  index with same name as constraint

Comment: Can you see if it is an unique index? This would explain why you cannot insert the same id twice.

Comment: Yes, is a unique index.Now make sense. I could insert null because the constraint was disable. But I couldn't insert duplicated because the index.

Comment: Exactly. This setup is rather unusual and confusing.

Comment: So the persons before me try to disable the constraints to remove the PK but forgot remove the index. That is why they call me. Now just need drop that index.