# How to create a primary key using a longer unique index?

Tags: sql, oracle

One can specify the index while creating the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE t (a NUMBER, b NUMBER);
ALTER TABLE t ADD PRIMARY KEY (a,b) USING INDEX (CREATE INDEX i ON t(a,b));
```

This works for column subsets, too:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD PRIMARY KEY (a) USING INDEX (CREATE INDEX i ON t(a,b));
```

I prefer unique indexes (because a non-unique index adds the rowid to each key which makes the index bigger and slightly slower). This works, too:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD PRIMARY KEY (a,b) USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i ON t(a,b));
```

However, subset *and* unique index results in an error:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD PRIMARY KEY (a) USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX u ON t(a,b));
ORA-14196: Specified index cannot be used to enforce the constraint.
```

To summarize:

```
OK     PRIMARY KEY (a,b) USING INDEX (        INDEX(a,b) )
OK     PRIMARY KEY (a,b) USING INDEX ( UNIQUE INDEX(a,b) )
OK     PRIMARY KEY (a)   USING INDEX (        INDEX(a,b) )
ERROR  PRIMARY KEY (a)   USING INDEX ( UNIQUE INDEX(a,b) )
```

I completely fail to understand why that is not possible.

I need it quite often, for instance for tables with two primary key columns (say country, city) and one further column (say population). As I always query the further column, a three column index would make sense. As the first two columns are unique (per primary key), the index will be unique as well, but Oracle won't let me do this. Why?

Comment: Interesting. I never noticed that adding a column to a primary key automatically [and silently] makes it `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Also, it's interesting that Oracle creates index `I` on the first example as `NONUNIQUE`.

Comment: "...because a non-unique index adds the rowid to each key..." -- why do you say so? All indexes include the pointer to the heap.

Comment: @TheImpaler it removes the not null silently, too, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670533/1864029)

Comment: @TheImpaler re rowid: Of course it has the rowid, but it adds it apparently to the key, too, see [here](https://richardfoote.files.wordpress.com/2007/12/compare-internal-index-storage-between-unique-and-non-unique-indexes.pdf)

Comment: @TheImpaler: You comment got me thinking, thanks! Richard has the details: Of course the rowid is included in each entry. For unique indexes, it is stored as (fixed length) rowid before the column values. For non-unique indexes, it is attached as the last column, including the normal length bit.  Therefore non-unique indexes have one byte more overhead than unique indexes. Much smaller than I assumed. [source](https://richardfoote.files.wordpress.com/2007/12/index-internals-rebuilding-the-truth.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section, and it may be blatantly wrong.

My take is that Oracle can enforce the uniqueness of primary keys using either 1) a unique index or 2) a non-unique index (functioanality that may exist for historical reasons). Therefore:

- Case #1: if it uses a unique index, all the heavy lifting of finding out if a value is unique is done by the index itself. It's part of its features.
- Case #2: if it uses a non-unique index, the index is used to store the values, but the uniqueness is validated by the primary key constraint itself that scans the index for multiple values.

Now, your four examples fall into:

- case #1 (non-unique)
- case #2 (unique)
- case #1 (non-unique)
- not case #1, not case #2. This is why I think Oracle does not allow this one.

And of course, if anyone knows better, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

the unique index on the column (a,b) cannot be used to enforce a primary key on the column (a) and the database has rigthly prevented you doing this action.

This is because (1,100),(1,101),(1,102) are are legitimate values in the unique index on (a,b) where are enforcing that column a contains only 1,2,3,...etc cannot be actioned using the same index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The values (1,100), (1,101), (1,102) are obviously legitimate values in a non-unique index. Why then is this non-unique index ok to enforce a primary key on (a), but not a unique index?

Comment: i read this too fast. Here is my guess, a unique index can hold (null,null) values, which is the reason why it didnt work. If however the columns of a and b is made as NOT NULL explicitly while creating the table, and after that if i were to create the primary key constraint using the unique index it could work out

Comment: I just tried that option (making the columns as not null) and then checking if that allows, but it failed

Comment: Overall i am guess since the rowid is not part of the unique index, and since unique index cannot diallow entire null values and therefore its being prevented from getting used

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Oracle indexes always exclude fully null entries such as (null, null). Actually that's the strategy that is used in Oracle to produce filtered (aka partial) indexes.

Comment: A unique index can hold (null, null)? No - that is a wrong guess. It can't.